# Convert xml dataset to csv, How to map % and IDs values?

Tags: xml, database

I want to convert XML files to CSV. But the names are in long IDs or enclosed in values like %574%. I want a meaningful result from this. How can I do that?
I am attaching a Drive link for the XML Files [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NFssctE1lONz30o8X9c1U4px13m-Jo4J?usp=share_link).

I got these files from a software called Autodesk Inventor. It has a materials database.
The dataset is supposed to look like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDeGV.png)

**I want to know how can I map them and create a single CSV File like in the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDeGV.png).**
[image]

**Small bit of data:**

> Mat.SI.res.xml

```
<Resources>
<string id="%1%" value="Materials (SI)"/>
<string id="%2%" value="Material Designation"/>
<string id="%3%" value="Heat treatment"/>
<string id="%4%" value="Tensile Strength"/>
<string id="%5%" value="MPa"/>
<string id="%6%" value="Yield Strength"/>
<string id="%7%" value="Pulling power"/>
<string id="%8%" value="Brinell Hardness Number"/>
<string id="%9%" value="Max. allowable compressive (Hertz) stress"/>
<string id="%10%" value="Modulus of Elasticity"/>
<string id="%11%" value="Shear Modulus"/>
<string id="%12%" value="Poisson's Ratio"/>
<string id="%13%" value="Density"/>
<string id="%14%" value="kg/m^3"/>
<string id="%15%" value="Description"/>
<string id="%16%" value="Steel SAE 1015"/>
<string id="%17%" value="as-rolled"/>
<string id="%18%" value="normalized"/>
```

> Mat.SI.xml

```
<FDesign>
<Table InternalName="53DEBB75-8166-44E4-A0B4-73996C40CB11">
    <Definition DisplayName="%1%">
        <Columns>
            <ID IsVisible="0" IsNumeric="0" EditableState="0" />
            <Material DisplayName="%574%" Description="%2%" Units="" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="0" EditableState="1" />
            <Std DisplayName="%565%" Description="%564%" Units="" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="0" IsRequired="1" EditableState="1" /> 
            <Heat DisplayName="%575%" Description="%3%" Units="" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="0" IsRequired="0" EditableState="1" />
            <Su DisplayName="%576%" Description="%4%" Units="%5%" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="1" IsRequired="1" EditableState="1" />
            <Sy DisplayName="%577%" Description="%6%" Units="%5%" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="1" IsRequired="1" EditableState="1" />
            <A5 DisplayName="%578%" Description="%7%" Units="%1287%" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="1" IsRequired="0" EditableState="1" />
            <Bhn DisplayName="%579%" Description="%8%" Units="%1286%" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="1" IsRequired="0" EditableState="1" />
            <pH DisplayName="%580%" Description="%9%" Units="%5%" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="1" IsRequired="0" EditableState="1" />
            <E DisplayName="%581%" Description="%10%" Units="%5%" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="1" IsRequired="1" EditableState="1" />
            <G DisplayName="%582%" Description="%11%" Units="%5%" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="1" IsRequired="1" EditableState="1" />
            <mi DisplayName="%583%" Description="%12%" Units="%1286%" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="1" IsRequired="1" EditableState="1" />
            <Ro DisplayName="%584%" Description="%13%" Units="%14%" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="1" IsRequired="1" EditableState="1" />
            <Desc DisplayName="%585%" Description="%15%" Units="" IsVisible="1" IsNumeric="0" EditableState="1" />
        </Columns>
    </Definition>
    <Data>
        <Row>
            <Std>%566%</Std>
            <ID>D8894772B88F495093C43AF905AB6373</ID>
            <Material>%16%</Material>
            <Heat>%17%</Heat>
            <Su>421</Su>
            <Sy>314</Sy>
            <A5>39</A5>
            <Bhn>126</Bhn>
            <pH></pH>
            <E>207000</E>
            <G>79000</G>
            <mi>0.3</mi>
            <Ro>7860</Ro>
            <Desc></Desc>
        </Row>
```

Comment: Hi! Questions here need to be self-contained - relevant details should be included as text in the question, not links or images. That generally means extracting a *small representative sample* (part of the general skill of *breaking the problem down*). You also need to say what programming language or tool you're asking for help with, and show some evidence of your attempts (or at least research) so far. See [ask] and the rest of the [help] for more tips.

Answer (score 2):

You are not showing any of the unicode headers in the data so cannot tell how to solver the header issues. Use following powershell script so convert xml to csv.  CSV is text and an unicode characters have to be escaped.  And then the viewer that is used has to be capable of displaying the unicode characters.

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$xmlFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$csvFilename = "c:\temp\test.csv"

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($xmlFilename)

$rows =  $xDoc.Descendants("Row").Foreach([System.Xml.Linq.XElement])
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($row in $rows)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   foreach($col in $row.Elements())
   {
      $name = $col.Name.LocalName
      $value = $col.Value 
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $name -NotePropertyValue $value
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$table | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilename
$table | format-Table
```